# How to refresh CBPeripheral to get advertisementData again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

I am able to get a list of `CBPeripheral` devices in following delegate method.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
   ...
}
```

Now, I am keeping reference to the connected `CBPeripheral` by creating a strong property for it.

Later time, if I want to access the `advertisementData` which I received in above delegate,  can I get it again from the reference of `peripheral` I kept previously.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to keep a reference to the `advertisementData` for each peripheral that the `CBCentralManager` discovers.

Comment: So this is the only way I can achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I don't see in the documentation any other place that the advertisemantData might be. I would suggest creating a <CBPeripheralDelegate> object that holds the CBPeripheral and and the corresponding advertisementData and use that for everything.

Comment: are you available for online support? I am ready to make payment if you can support me for my on-going project. I stuck in middle of something. If you are available for ~2 hours, you can reach me out inside my SO profile. You can find my email over there.